# static/non static error not sure how to resolve this in the right way

Tags: java, android

I have an image adapter which is taking images from instagram and putting them in a grid layout. I want to be able to click on the image and enlarge it to full screen.

I looked at an online tutorial similar tto this and I made the following changes to my code...

I made an interface...

```
public interface ImageClickListener{
     void onClick(int position);
}
```

I made sure my main activity implemented this interface by adding implement at the top like so...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageClickListener
```

lastly I made changes to the holder class in my adapter like so...

```
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private ImageView mPhoto1, mPhoto2;
        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mPhoto1 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            //mPhoto2 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ImageClickListener.onClick(getLayoutPosition()); //*** problem here
        }
    }
```

the issue is quite clear and I dont know how to resolve it... What I thought was ill do something like...

imageclicklistener listener = new imageclick... so on and so forth in the holder but that didnt work so well. When I make the onclick method in the interface static then I obviously wont be able to use it in my main.

Comment: You need an instance of `ImageClickListener` on which to invoke the `onClick` method.

Comment: Yes I realise that but I dont know where to do this...

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainActivity` is the one you want to act as the `ImageClickListener`. You can pass it in as an argument to the constructor when creating your customer adapter and then keep a reference to it.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Holder> {
    private ImageClickListener imageClickListener;
    public MyAdapter(ImageClickListener imageClickListener, other params...) {
        this.imageClickListener = imageClickListener;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If your `Holder` is an inner class of your adapter you can then do:

```
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ImageView mPhoto1, mPhoto2;
    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mPhoto1 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageClickListener.onClick(getLayoutPosition());
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity` where you create the adapter it will look like this:

```
private MyAdapter myAdapter; // class field

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // this refers to the MainActivity being passed in as the ImageClickListener
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, restOfArgs...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well but it didnt solve my problem. Here are the changes that I made....I made a new imgclicklistener in the adapter and passed it into the constructor and set it. in my main at the top i also defined a new imageclicklistener and later on initialized it. It didnt give any errors but it didnt work as expected. when i clicked on the pictures they didnt go full screen.

Comment: public void onClick(int position) {
        Picture selectedPicture = mAdapter.getSelectedPicture(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", selectedPicture);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

Comment: Something sounds goofy about what you are saying about defining/initializing a new `ImageClickListener`. You don't need to declare one since the `MainActivity` is your `ImageClickListener`. Make sure you are declaring your adapter similar to what I have in the updated answer except using your adapter class name of course.

Comment: I make the changes except for the last one, It gives me an error and im sorry im confused but I dont understand how we can pass the main activity as reference when the adapter constructor is looking for a imageclicklistener? I think i followed you step by step except for the last part.

Comment: You can pass into the constructor anything that implements an `ImageClickListener`. Since your `MainActivity` implements `ImageClickListener` in the code you provided this is why you can pass it in as a reference to the adapter constructor. `MainActivity` is an `ImageClickListener`. If things still aren't working add the new relevant code in `MainActivity` where you are creating the adapter and maybe even your adapter code.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to know what error you are experiencing.